# Derive polynomial from stationary points

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, polynomials

So it's a relatively simple question which extensive google'ing has not yielded any answers. Is it possible to derive the equation of a polynomial if you know it's stationary points/inflection points?

I ask this because I have points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ with gradients $0$, and a point of inflection at point $(\frac12,\frac12)$ that I must match with a polynomial to produce an sigmoid-esque curve.

If this is possible please tell me how, thanks!

Comment: Does the point of inflection have to have zero gradient as well, because if not, a cubic would suffice.

Comment: @DavidQuinn No, It should preferably have a gradient > 1

Comment: So there are two not three stationary points?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Damn - I'll edit the mistake out of my question, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that the curve is cubic, then since there ate stationary points at $x=0,1$, then the derivative is of the form $$\frac{dy}{dx}=kx(x-1)$$

Integrating this and applying the conditions $x=0,y=0$ and $x=1,y=1$ gives $$y=-2x^3+3x^2$$